# Why does my Entity Framework turn '2.87' into just '2' (decimal field)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, entity-framework, decimal, precision

I verfied that the correct value '2.87' is coming into the service.. and accord to the EF diagram the type for the 'Score' field is 'Decimal'... But in the database it says just '2'

```
   [OperationContract]
        public void AddHighScore(string strName, decimal dScore, int iLevel)
        {
            using (SQL2008R2_789485_punkouterEntities1 dc = new SQL2008R2_789485_punkouterEntities1())
            {
                HighScore oHighScore = new HighScore();
                oHighScore.Level = iLevel;
                oHighScore.Name = strName;
                //oHighScore.Name = dScore.ToString();
                oHighScore.Score = dScore;
                dc.AddToHighScores(oHighScore);
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }
        }


-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating table 'HighScores'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HighScores] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Score] decimal(18,0)  NOT NULL,
    [Level] int  NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to set the scale on the decimal field. Change the Score field to be decimal(18,2)

[See Decimal help File on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

You can set the Scale in EF by first selecting the field, then in the properties window you will see a property for Scale (see image)

[image]

Comment: There a way I can set this in The Entity Designer?

Comment: @punkouter I edited my posting with an image where you can set the Scale in Entity Framework

Comment: I found that earlier.. and it said none and I clicked on it and saw nothing.. then I tried (18,2) and that didnt work.. but ok.. i get it now . thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`decimal(18,0)` means a decimal number with 18 digits to the left of the decimal point, and **0** to the right.

Therefore, your value is being stored as `2`. I suggest using `decimal(18,2)` or similar, which allows 18 digits, with up to 2 to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: Ok thanks. Though if I can't set this in the entity designer somehow then Ill have to manually change the genreated sql.. thats a pain.

Answer (score -1):

Change your column datatype to [Money (instead of decimal)](http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/12/20/ef4-code-first-control-unicode-and-decimal-precision-scale-with.aspx) and regen your edmx.

Comment: -1: there is no such type, at least in C#. And if you meant VisualBasic, please note that it's Money == C#'s decimal.

Comment: I think @misskitty says about sql money