# EF truncated the scale in decimal while retrieving the record from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a column `Price` in one of my SQL Server tables:

```
Price   decimal(20, 2)
```

In model generated by Entity Framework, it looks like this:

```
public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
```

When retrieving the record, I get only 3 instead of 3.15! What could be the issue?

```
            Entity_Product eProduct = new Entity_Product();
            var pr = new DataModel.Entity_Product();
            pr = Init.ProductRepository.GetById(ProductId);

            eProduct.Name = pr.Name;
            eProduct.CommercialName = pr.CommercialName;
            eProduct.PackageType = pr.PackageType;
            eProduct.DrugType = pr.DrugType;
            eProduct.DrugCode = pr.DrugCode;
            eProduct.ProductId = pr.ProductId;
            eProduct.Administration = pr.Administration;
            eProduct.Manufacturer = pr.Manufacturer;
            eProduct.Price = pr.Price;
            eProduct.Strength = pr.Strength;
            eProduct.StregnthUnit = pr.StregnthUnit; 
            eProduct.Barcode = pr.Barcode;
            eProduct.IsEnabled = pr.IsEnabled;
            eProduct.CreatedOn = pr.CreatedOn;
            eProduct.CreatedBy = pr.CreatedBy;
            eProduct.UpdatedOn = pr.UpdatedOn;
            eProduct.UpdatedBy = pr.UpdatedBy;
            return eProduct;

    public T GetById(params object[] idies)
    {
        return ContextProvider.Set<T>().Find(idies);
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you are comparing the same row and querying the same database, table/view. Also post the code you are using to retrieve the record and seeing the value.

Comment: Please post your SQL query for more clarification

Comment: @EzLo, Yes I am referring to correct row. Double checked !

Comment: @ReyanChougle I am not using any sql queries, using EF with generic repository and GetById(int id) function.

Comment: Can you share the code written in GetById method

Comment: @ReyanChougle Updated with code

Comment: What version of EF do you use?
Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first

Comment: @VladimirP. Mine is DB first approach, version  v6.0.0.0

Comment: @VladimirP. The link you gave is for Codefirst. Possible to use the same in DBfirst also ?

Comment: @Anuya Did you try just to override OnModelCreating method in your context class derivided from DbContext as it's done in link I gave you?

Comment: @VladimirP.Yes tried. But when building the app, the code which I put disappeared. It generates again -> Model.Context.cs

Comment: @Anuya https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551790/why-does-my-entity-framework-turn-2-87-into-just-2-decimal-field

Comment: @VladimirP. It is already set to Precision 20 and Scale 2

Comment: @Anuya if you change Nullable<decimal> to decimal it should work

Comment: @Anuya also I think you can try to use 2 variants:
Price decimal(20, 2) NOT NULL with decimal in c#
or
Price decimal(20, 2) NULL and decimal? in c# (alias of Nullable<decimal>)
and see what EF will generate

Comment: Are you sure the values are being truncated?  It just may be the method you are using to debug (view the data) that is truncating the numbers.